# The number of distinct points with hexagons.

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering how many distinct points can there be in a figure containing hexagons joined in a football manner. I searched it online and the usual answer was 60 which is true for ordinary footballs. But if there were larger footballs with many more hexagons, say "n", then what would be the number of distinct points. I saw a similar problem in presh Talwalker YouTube channel mind your decisions but couldn't understand it. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "football" is a spherical version of a [truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron). It has 32 faces : 20 hexagons (all the same size) and 12 pentagons.

It belongs to the larger class of [**Goldberg polyhedra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron). I believe it is what you need when you ask for "more hexagons". The common features with the truncated icosahedron is that they are made of hexagons and pentagons, with an increased number of hexagons, but now **with 2 different sizes** (at least in the first category, featured green and yellow on the Wikipedia site) whereas, oddly, they keep the same number of pentagons (12)!

Take a look at these [animations](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedra.html).

Comment: The classic football, along with the more trivial dodecahedron, are the only two where the vertices are on a sphere and at the same time the polygons are regular. If you want the other Golberg polyhedra to have regular polygons, they will look like big, rounded icosahedra where the vertices are the original pentagons. As seen on the wikipedia link given above.

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks for the editing. Will think to it next time !

Comment: This was very informative. Thank you, people.